# Tel and SMS Links Not Working in TWebbrowser Within Delphi XE5 Android App

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I've been struggling with this for days, and would appreciate any help anyone can give.  Tel: and SMS: links work just fine in any web browser on Android.  But they do not work at all from within TWebBrowser.

I found this [code for opening links natively,](http://delphi.org/2013/10/sending-a-url-to-another-app-on-android-and-ios-with-delphi-xe5/) which works fine, but I cannot figure out how to fire a function from within TWebBrowser.  There are a few Windows-only solutions around involving type libraries, but nothing that seems to work on Android.

Is there some way to call a native function from a web page in TWebBrowser in a Delphi XE5 Firemonkey mobile app?  Alternatively, is there a way to actually get Tel and SMS links working within TWebBrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering about this, as stated in my question, TWebbrowser on XE5 on Android doesn't open some of the most useful links you would find in a webview app - namely SMS, Tel, or Mailto links.

I solved this by rewriting the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function in FMX.Webbrowser.Android.  In order to use the modified unit, copy FMX.Webbrowser.Android.pas to your project directory, then add it to your project.  Then change the following original function:

```
    function TAndroidWebBrowserService.TWebBrowserListener.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
  P1: JWebView; P2: JString): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;
```

to

```
    function TAndroidWebBrowserService.TWebBrowserListener.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
  P1: JWebView; P2: JString): Boolean;
  var
  oUrl,lURL:string;
  intent:jintent;
begin
oUrl:=jstringtostring(p2);
lUrl:=lowercase(oURL);
if ((pos('sms:',lUrl)>0) or (pos('tel:',lUrl)>0) or (pos('mailto:',lUrl)>0)) then
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(oURL)));
  try
    SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
    p1.stopLoading;
    exit(true);
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      exit(false);
    end;
  end;
  exit(true);
end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

That's about it.  The default location for FMX.Webbrowser.Android is C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\source\fmx

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using events TWebBrowser (FMX)
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest
and
onDidFailLoadWithError

```
    procedure TForm9.WebBrowser1DidFailLoadWithError(ASender: TObject);
    begin
      if (BackByError) then
      begin
        ProccessURL;
        Timer2.Enabled := True;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm9.WebBrowser1ShouldStartLoadWithRequest(ASender: 
                                                            TObject;   
                                                       const URL: string);
    var
      IPos1, IPos2 : Integer;
      aURL : String;
    begin
      aURL := URL;
      IPos1 := Pos('tel:', aURL);
      IPos2 := Pos('mailto:', aURL);
      BackByError := (IPos1 > 0) or (IPos2 > 0);
      if (BackByError) then
        URLError := aURL;
    end;

    procedure TForm9.ProccessURL;
    var
      i : JIntent;
      Uri : JNet_Uri;
    begin
      Uri := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(stringtojstring(URLError));
      i := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW, Uri);
      try
        SharedActivity.startActivity(i);
      except
        on e: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage('Error: ' + e.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm9.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if (BackByError) and (WebBrowser1.CanGoBack) then
      begin
        BackByError := False;
        WebBrowser1.GoBack;
        Timer2.Enabled := False;
      end;
    end;
```